# AutoMoqCustomization throws "Could not load file or assembly ..." exception

Tags: nunit, moq, autofixture, automoq

Has anybody an idea why this exception happens when I call following code:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
var productRecords = fixture.CreateMany<ProductRecord>();
```

I updated all NuGet Packages:

- Moq - 4.8.3
- AutoFixture.AutoMoq 4.4.0

> TestClass ....
>
> AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath : AutoFixture was unable
>   to create an instance from AutoFixture.Kernel.MultipleRequest because
>   creation unexpectedly failed with exception. Please refer to the inner
>   exception to investigate the root cause of the failure.
>
> Request path:
>
> Inner exception messages:     System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Moq, Version=4.1.1308.2120, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> ----> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Moq, Version=4.1.1308.2120, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    at
>   AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   AutoFixture.BehaviorRoot.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext
>   context)    at AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   AutoFixture.Fixture.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at AutoFixture.Kernel.SpecimenContext.Resolve(Object request)    at
>   AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.CreateMany[T](ISpecimenContext context)
>   at AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.CreateMany[T](ISpecimenBuilder builder)
>   at Test.Test.DataImport2.ServiceTest.SetupCommonMocks() in
>   C:\Development\DataImport2\ServiceTest.cs:line 42    at
>   Test.Test.DataImport2.ServiceTest() in
>   C:\Development\DataImport2\ServiceTest.cs:line 84
>   --FileLoadException    at AutoFixture.AutoMoq.MockPostprocessor.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   AutoFixture.CustomizationNode.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext
>   context)    at
>   AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)

I tried to:

- Update Nuget packages (uninstall/reinstall)
- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project
- Restart Rider

Nothing works

Comment: Have you tried adding an assembly binding redirect?

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/1002) for reference.